What exactly causes the angular component to rerender if not change detection?
Apparently I have a huge missunderstanding about angular's internals.
Consider the following situation:
@Component({
  selector: 'banana',
  template: ` <h1>We have {{ item.x }} bananas.</h1> `,
})
export class Banana implements {
  @Input() item: { x: number } = { x: 0 };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<banana [item]="item"></banana>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  protected item = { x: 0 };

  constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.item.x = Math.random();
    }, 1000);
  }
}

Up to this day I thought that this would not work (i.e. the changed item.x value would not be displayed), because I learned that angular change detection would do shallow comparisons per default.
Indeed, in the docs we find the following:

Modifying object references. In case an input receives a mutable object as value and you modify the object but preserve the reference, Angular will not invoke change detection. That’s the expected behavior because the previous and the current value of the input point to the same reference.

To my surprise, the example above does indeed work. My question is: Why? What exactly causes the view to update and what relation does this reason have with change detection?
This blog post talks about a similar situation (where the author renders the first but not the last name nested property). But modifying my example above to display the changes:
[...] implements OnChanges { 

[...]

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(changes);
}

yields no logs - in my undestanding this means that change detection did not detect any changes (as expected due to the cited paragraph from the docs).
So what is going on here?
Update: As pointed out in an answer, setInterval causes a view update "because of ngzone" (does this mean setInterval is a performance issue per se?).
But what about arrays? array.push does obviously not change the array reference and should not let a change be detected, but still it causes a view rendering things from the array in a loop to update. Why so?

Firstly, both banana and the main component have the same reference in memory, so naturally, updating one also updates the other, because they are pointing to the same location. Arrays and objects are stored by reference to memory!
The code you put inside the setInterval causes the NgZone to trigger change detection, which you can check with the hook ngDoCheck. This is what causes the update, you can check this by making the code run outside NgZone using runOutsideAngular. Here the change detection won't run!
  constructor(private zone: NgZone) {
    zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.item.x = Math.random();
      }, 1000);
    })
  }

Stackblitz Demo - no NgZone.runOutsideAngular!

The ngOnChanges run only when the memory reference changes, so when we do this.item = { ...this.item }; this creates a new memory reference and ngOnChanges is fired!
stackblitz Demo Working
References:

Angular Change detection

Angular Change detection article



Do you mean { ...this.item } ?

@T_01 Thanks!, yes empty setInterval, also triggers change detection, but its due to NgZone, which looks out for these asynchronous tasks!

Okay so setInterval just forces the component to rerender completely. Things like {{ Math.random() }} or any function calls are reevaluating.

"> Firstly, both banana and the main component have the same reference in memory, so naturally, updating one also updates the other, because they are pointing to the same location. Arrays and objects are stored by reference to memory!"
I mean, this is clear - but what about arrays? If I do array.push(), why does the view update here? is this also some ngZone shenanigans?

@T_01 Basically, if you want to add something it happens on a hook, during that time change detection runs after few hooks like ngOnInit, if you look at the other ways, like pressing a button, setInterval, setTimeout, or browser events, change detection will get triggered and thus capture the scenarios! This is my understanding!
